# Unexpected linq behaviour on 'select', 'where not null' and 'distinct' (ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, linq, null, ado.net

In a list of ADO.NET rows, I want to do a select and get related data from another table, where that data is present.

I notice now strangely that these 2 queries behave differently, the first one returning (in my case) 0, the 2nd one 1 result:

```
myRows.Select(row=>row.OtherRow).Where(row=>row!=null).Distinct()

myRows.Where(row=>row.OtherRow != null).Select(row=>row.OtherRow).Distinct()
```

I am clueless as to why. As far as I could see (though this also should not matter from my understanding), there were no null values in the OtherRow. Any explanation?

Comment: Have you examined sql query generated in each case?

Comment: Are these being executed on in memory data or are these being converted into sql queries?

Comment: In memory, so should not have anything to do with SQL. It is Ado.net after all, not pure EF.

Comment: Could you please provide more code where `myRows` come from?

Comment: Yeah, a [mcve] would really help here. Nothing looks wrong with that code, and nothing should cause this to happen.

Comment: I can't figure out a way to provide that data since it comes from a DB. I would not know what is relevant, apart from the row not being null.